# Are all adjacency matrices represented by 0 and 1s?

Tags: graphs, adjacency-matrix

Are there any cases when adjacency matrix should have entries other than 0 and 1?

Comment: This could have been answered just by looking at [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix): for example, the section "[variations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjacency_matrix#Variations)" gives the example of $(a,b,c)$-adjacency matrices. You are expected to do some basic research before asking questions here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, because the `(i,j)`th entry simply talks about whether or not there *exists* an edge from vertex `i` to vertex `j`, and represents existence by a `1` and non-existence by a `0`.

However, many graph representations store the edge weight instead of `1`s in the matrix. This way, a single matrix can compactly represent both the edges and their weights.

Comment: Got it, the weights

Comment: Note that, if you want to have an edge whose weight is zero, you can't use a single matrix to represent both the adjacencies and the weight. (Unless you represent non-edges by $-\infty$, but then you can't represent edges with weight $-\infty$ and so on.)

Comment: ^ Point noted. (Incidentally, I was just going through an OCW lecture where the solution to a problem involved using "dummy" zero-weight edges.)